# Why do my jQuery buttons not display on my dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XLVDD/1/). I've used the jQuery dialogs before and this is the exact same code that I'm using in another project. The only difference is that I'm getting the jQuery libraries from google instead of hosting them myself:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js">  </script>


<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Confirmation Required" > 
            <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Do you want to delete?</p> 
        </div>
<a href="http://google.com" class="deleteLink">Test Dialog</test>
```

Then I have a script like this:

```
 $(document).ready( function () {
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  resizable: false,
  height:180,
});

$(".deleteLink").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");

$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    buttons : {
    "Confirm" : function() {
        window.location.href = targetUrl;
    },
    "Cancel" : function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
    }
});

$("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
});

} );
```

The dialog shows up as expected but the buttons (Confirm/Cancel) do not show up. I think I'm loading all the relevant jQuery libraries and the CSS file. Is there something else I'm missing?

I've used FireBug to verify that it does call the button setting code, but still no buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reason your code may not be working now could be due to you using an older version of jQuery or jQuery UI either way here is a possible fix:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
var targetUrl;
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  resizable: false,
  height:180,
  buttons: {
    "Confirm" : function() {
        window.location.href = targetUrl;
    },
    "Cancel" : function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
    }
});

$(".deleteLink").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
targetUrl = $(this).attr("href")    
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
});
});
```

the buttons should be assigned when you create the .dialog function, to still be able to pass the URL when the button is clicked I created the targetURL globally, then you can assign it in the click function and still access it in the dialog function

**sorry forgot to move the link to make it work :) should be fine now, also here is a link to the fiddle, the linking action doesnt seem to work in fiddle but I tested it with an alert and it is passing ok: http://jsfiddle.net/GordnFreeman/wbGax/

Comment: You're right. The old jQuery API was letting me do it the wrong way.

Comment: glad it worked out for you, I have had similar things happen to me (which is why I now try and avoid linking to the latest version) stuff like that can creep when they do updates

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring the dialog twice. Just combine them and the buttons show up.

```
 $(document).ready( function () {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      resizable: false,
      height:180,
      buttons : {
        "Confirm" : function() {
            window.location.href = targetUrl;
        },
        "Cancel" : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
     }
});
```

Updated [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XLVDD/17/)

Comment: the dialog doesnt open automaticly its opened by the .deleteLink click function later on in the page

Comment: @Gordnfreeman beat you to it. I was defining the dialog twice. I never noticed in the older versions because it just allowed me to do that. Thanks.